# Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Teja>' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, http

Trato de hacer una petición http simple pero obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensé que talvez mi archivo php estaba devolviendo algún valor en nulo pero revise la respuesta con Postman y todos los campos están completos:

```
[
{
  "codigo_teja":"1320897",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"2.44",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"2.3",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"2.415",
  "teja_peso":"29.9",
  "teja_precio":"15",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1320898",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"3.05",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"2.91",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"3.055",
  "teja_peso":"35",
  "teja_precio":"16",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1321215",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"1.52",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"1.38",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"1.449",
  "teja_peso":"18.2",
  "teja_precio":"13",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1321218",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"0.6",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"0.46",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"0.483",
  "teja_peso":"7.5",
  "teja_precio":"10",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1321231",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"0.9",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"0.76",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"0.798",
  "teja_peso":"11.0",
  "teja_precio":"11",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1321234",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"1.2",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"1.06",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"1.113",
  "teja_peso":"15.0",
  "teja_precio":"12",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1329896",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"1.83",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"1.69",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"1.7745",
  "teja_peso":"22",
  "teja_precio":"14",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
}
]
```

Estas son las clases que tengo:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'Tejas.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PageHome(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class PageHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retrieve JSON Flutter'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getTejas(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return _ListaTejas(snapshot.data);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ListaTejas extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Teja> tejas;

  _ListaTejas(this.tejas);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("Imprimir resultado"),
    );
  }
}

Future<Teja> getTejas() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://duralit.com/obtener_tejas.php")).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
  debugPrint("LOG" + response.body);
  return tejaFromJson(response.body);
}
```

Tejas.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Teja tejaFromJson(String str) => Teja.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String tejaToJson(Teja data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Teja {
  Teja({
    required this.codigoTeja,
    required this.tejaCodigo,
    required this.tejaLongitud,
    required this.tejaAncho,
    required this.tejaLongitudEfectiva,
    required this.tejaAnchoEfectivo,
    required this.tejaAreaEfectiva,
    required this.tejaPeso,
    required this.tejaPrecio,
    required this.tejaFoto,
    required this.tejaEstado,
  });

  String codigoTeja = '';
  String tejaCodigo = '';
  String tejaLongitud = '';
  String tejaAncho = '';
  String tejaLongitudEfectiva = '';
  String tejaAnchoEfectivo = '';
  String tejaAreaEfectiva = '';
  String tejaPeso = '';
  String tejaPrecio = '';
  String tejaFoto = '';
  String tejaEstado = '';

  factory Teja.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Teja(
    codigoTeja: json["codigo_teja"],
    tejaCodigo: json["teja_codigo"],
    tejaLongitud: json["teja_longitud"],
    tejaAncho: json["teja_ancho"],
    tejaLongitudEfectiva: json["teja_longitud_efectiva"],
    tejaAnchoEfectivo: json["teja_ancho_efectivo"],
    tejaAreaEfectiva: json["teja_area_efectiva"],
    tejaPeso: json["teja_peso"],
    tejaPrecio: json["teja_precio"],
    tejaFoto: json["teja_foto"],
    tejaEstado: json["teja_estado"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "codigo_teja": codigoTeja,
    "teja_codigo": tejaCodigo,
    "teja_longitud": tejaLongitud,
    "teja_ancho": tejaAncho,
    "teja_longitud_efectiva": tejaLongitudEfectiva,
    "teja_ancho_efectivo": tejaAnchoEfectivo,
    "teja_area_efectiva": tejaAreaEfectiva,
    "teja_peso": tejaPeso,
    "teja_precio": tejaPrecio,
    "teja_foto": tejaFoto,
    "teja_estado": tejaEstado,
  };
}
```

Algo curioso que note es de que cuando imprimo los resultado en la consola aparece incompleto:

```
[
{
  "codigo_teja":"1320897",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"2.44",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"2.3",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"2.415",
  "teja_peso":"29.9",
  "teja_precio":"15",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1320898",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"3.05",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"2.91",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"3.055",
  "teja_peso":"35",
  "teja_precio":"16",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1321215",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja_longitud":"1.52",
  "teja_ancho":"1.09",
  "teja_longitud_efectiva":"1.38",
  "teja_ancho_efectivo":"1.05",
  "teja_area_efectiva":"1.449",
  "teja_peso":"18.2",
  "teja_precio":"13",
  "teja_foto":"https:\/\/duralit.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Teja-Flexiteja.png",
  "teja_estado":"1"
},
{
  "codigo_teja":"1321218",
  "teja_codigo":"TF",
  "teja
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que esperas, es un Listado de Tejas, no solo una Teja, lo puedes notar en tu JSON de respuestas, que empieza con un corchete "[", luego de es tiene objetos/maps, que serían de la clase `Teja`, entonces necesitas un método adicional para transformar eso.

Primero elimina este método, ya que solo te retorna una `Teja`

```dart
Teja tejaFromJson(String str) => Teja.fromJson(json.decode(str));
```

Lo cual es incorrecto. Debes de definirlo así:

```dart
List<Teja> tejaFromJson(String str) => List<Teja>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Teja.fromJson(x)));
```

Entonces al momento de hacer el parseo y el llamado al API lo usarías así:

```dart
Future<List<Teja>> getTejas() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://duralit.com/obtener_tejas.php")).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
  debugPrint("LOG" + response.body);
  return tejaFromJson(response.body);
}
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias.